# What is the difference between codehaus.mojo build helper plugin's goal "add-resource" vs maven install plugin's goal "install-file"?

Tags: maven, plugins, resources, installation

I am trying to understand when to use which plugins. As far as I can tell build helper plugin copy the file from the project and maven install plugin adds it to the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resource is something to package into your artifact, usually an additional file that is needed at runtime.

Dependencies are not resources. To use a jar that is not in any known maven repository, you need to install it first into your local repository. Then you can use it as dependency.